# Outlook form in Visual Studio

Tags: forms, visual-studio, outlook

I have a macro in Outlook which uses a basic form to print the most recent *n* parts of an email.  All works great and so now to deploy properly I want to write it as an Outlook add-in in Visual Studio Pro.

I am fairly comfortable with the code side converting my VBA to VB.NET but I am not sure how to get started with the form.  In Outlook it was just a case of choosing Insert...UserForm and then using the toolbox to design it to look like this:

[image: Outlook form]

How do I start to build a form like this in Visual Studio 2017 please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Windows Form by adding a new form to the add-in project. See [How to: Add Windows Forms to a Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2xxdce3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. In the code you just need to create an instance of the form and call the `Show` method:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Show();
```

Also you may consider creating a form region which can be displayed as a part of the mail item (in the same window). See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).